# Why is repo sync not checking out the branch I had specified in the manifest file?

Tags: git, repo

Suppose I have the following manifest file for the [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) tool ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example%20MCVE)
script is included at the end of this post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="repo1" fetch="/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos" />
  <remote name="repo2" fetch="/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos" />
  <default remote="repo1" revision="master" />
  <project name="repo1" path="repo1" />
  <project name="repo2" path="repo2"  />
</manifest>
```

I'm able to run `repo init ...` followed by `repo sync` into a brand
new directory (i.e., without any prior contents). But when I cd into
the resulting `repo1` subdirectory (e.g.,
`/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area/myproject/repo1/`), and do a `git status` I see this:

```
$ git status
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And then showing what branches are available I see:

```
$ git branch -a
* (no branch)
  remotes/m/master -> repo1/master
  remotes/repo1/master
```

Why did `repo sync` not check out to the default branch (`master`) that I
had specified in the `default` tag in the manifest file?

### Similar questions

This is similar to [Why doesn't git repo checkout the branch specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60921066/257924) but is
not quite the same issue. My issue is that **no branch** is checked
out, and that seems wrong.  I should not have to do anything else
other than the `repo sync`, and I should not have to run `git checkout master` in all of the repositories managed by that manifest file.

This also seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264612/257924
but using `repo init -b master` does not do what I want either (has no
effect on this problem of the repositories not being checked out to
the specified branch).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16917618/257924 gets close to answering
this question, but does not explain why `git branch -a` does not
contain the `master` branch right after the `repo sync`.

### Repo tool version

The [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) tool was pulled from source directly on 2021-11-15 via:

curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin/repo

and the PATH set to include `/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin`.

### [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function generate_repo {
  local repo_num="$1"
  mkdir -p /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/repo$repo_num.git
  cd /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/repo$repo_num.git
  git init --bare

  mkdir -p /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area
  git clone /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/repo$repo_num.git || {
    echo ERROR: git clone /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/repo$repo_num.git
    exit 1
  }

  (
    cd repo$repo_num
    touch repo$repo_num.README
    git add repo$repo_num.README
    git commit -m "Add repo$repo_num.README"
    git push origin
  )

  (
    mkdir -p /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area/repo$repo_num.test_clone
    cd /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area/repo$repo_num.test_clone
    git clone /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/repo$repo_num.git
    ls -ld repo$repo_num/*
    cd repo$repo_num
    git status
  )
}

# Remove the entire set of git repos for reproducable execution:
rm -rf /tmp/standalone_repo_expt

# Generate the git repositories, that we wish to combine into one
# larger directory, using the repo tool:
generate_repo 1
generate_repo 2

# Install the repo tool from source, not using any package managers:
mkdir -p /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin/repo 
test -s /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin/repo || {
  echo "ERROR: Failed to download repo tool into /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin/repo"
  exit 1
}
chmod a+rx /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin/repo
PATH="/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/bin:${PATH}"
which repo >& /dev/null || {
  echo "ASSERTION FAILED: Failed to install the repo tool."
  exit 1
}

# Create the git repository that houses the manifest that are needed
# by the repo tool that reference the git repositories generated
# above:
mkdir -p /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/manifests.git
cd /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/manifests.git
git init --bare

# Clone the manifest bare repo so we can add the manifest file, and
# push it back:
cd /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area
git clone /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/manifests.git || {
  echo ERROR: git clone /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/manifests.git failed
  exit 1
}
cd manifests
cat > default.xml <<EOF.manifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="repo1" fetch="/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos" />
  <remote name="repo2" fetch="/tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos" />
  <default remote="repo1" revision="master" />
  <project name="repo1" path="repo1" />
  <project name="repo2" path="repo2"  />
</manifest>
EOF.manifest

cat default.xml

git add default.xml
git commit -m "Manifest file used by the repo tool"
git push origin || {
  echo ERROR: git push origin failed
  exit 1
}

set -x
mkdir -p /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area/myproject
cd /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/work_area/myproject
repo init /tmp/standalone_repo_expt/git.repos/manifests.git
repo sync

cd repo1
pwd
ls -l
git status
```

Comment: I have no idea *why* Repo did what it did, but the answer for [tag:git] is "just go check out master directly".  Obviously this isn't the answer you want. (Perhaps you want to drop the [tag:git] tag.)

Comment: `repo sync` is designed to checkout a detached HEAD. I thinks it's because a revision specified in the manifest is not always the current head of a branch. It could be an old commit of a branch, or just a tag, or just a random commit of a ref. To sync the code exactly the same with the revisions specified in the manifest, I suggest you use `repo sync -d` so that even if the existing repository has checked out a branch, it always goes back to the specified revision as a detached HEAD. You could find more in repo's source code, mainly in `.repo/repo/subcmds/sync.py` and `.repo/repo/project.py`.

Comment: As to `repo init -b master`, the master means the master branch of the repository that holds the manifests. The manifest repository is specified by `-u <url>`.

Comment: @ElpieKay ok, well, then I really don't see the utility of this repo tool. It would rather make more sense for `repo sync` to check out the branch that I have specified in the `revision` attributes, versus leaving all of the repositories in a detached HEAD, forcing me to explicitly execute `git checkout <branch>` in each repository.

Comment: @bgoodr Consider the manifest as a `tag` for a number of repositories. It takes the snapshot of all the involved repositories.  If all the repositories have the same branch name, you could use `repo start --all <branch>` to checkout the branch. If they don't, you could use `repo forall` with `-r <pattern>` or `-g <groups>` to execute `git checkout <branch>` in specified repositories. If you take part in AOSP development, I think you would find its utility.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you. That's is helpful, since it revealed the very bug in the [repo start docs](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo#start) that led me astray, and I quote: "Begins a new branch for development, starting from the revision specified in the manifest." which is wrong because `repo start` requires the user to specify a `<branch>` on the command line, and does not do a `git checkout` "from the revision specified in the manifest".  If it did the latter, then it should run `git checkout <revision>` where `<revision>` _could_ be different on each repository being checked out.

Comment: @ElpieKay But, having said the last sentence above where the `<revision>` _could_ be different, etc., perhaps that is your point with "take part in AOSP" development, which is not my end-goal here, in that that is the way AOSP development works somehow. So, is there something specifically wrong about having `repo start` checkout the branches specified in the manifest, versus requiring the user to somehow just know which branch they need for _all_ repos?

Comment: What does "MSE" stand for?

Comment: @MichaelBurr You got me on that one. It means MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so I edited that in. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

`repo` doesn't create a local branch for you. When you check out a remote branch you'll end up with a detached head (since you can't make commits on the remote branch anyway).

https://groups.google.com/g/repo-discuss/c/yPoPazTRgMA

Comment: Yes, this was discovered and referred to in the comments of my original post. At least for now I've given up on using this tool, because it does not do what I wanted to do, and the amount of work I will have to invest in it to force it to do my bidding is excessive in my use cases.